# How to best build a persistent binary tree from a sorted stream

Tags: algorithm, scala, binary-tree, persistent-data

For a side project I wanted a simple way to generate a persistent binary search tree from a sorted stream. After some cursory searching I was only able to find descriptions of techniques that involved storing a sorted array where you can access any element by index. I ended up writing something that works but I figured this is well trodden territory and a canonical example is probably documented somewhere (and probably has a name).

The make shift code I made is included just for clarity. (It's also short)

```
object TreeFromStream {
  sealed trait ImmutableTree[T] {
    def height: Int
  }
  case class ImmutableTreeNode[T](
    value: T,
    left: ImmutableTree[T],
    right: ImmutableTree[T]
  ) extends ImmutableTree[T] {
    lazy val height = left.height + 1
  }
  case class NilTree[T]() extends ImmutableTree[T] {
    def height = 0
  }

  @tailrec
  def treeFromStream[T](
    stream: Stream[T],
    tree: ImmutableTree[T] = NilTree[T](),
    ancestors: List[ImmutableTreeNode[T]] = Nil
  ): ImmutableTree[T] = {
    (stream, ancestors) match {
      case (Stream.Empty, _) =>
        ancestors.foldLeft(tree) { case(right, root) => root.copy(right=right) }
      case (_, ancestor :: nextAncestors) if ancestor.left.height == tree.height =>
        treeFromStream(stream, ancestor.copy(right=tree), nextAncestors)
      case (next #:: rest, _) => 
        treeFromStream(
          rest, NilTree(),
          ImmutableTreeNode(next, tree, NilTree()) :: ancestors
        )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Comment: I don't read or write scala, so won't comment on your code. If you know the number of nodes in advance, you can generate a [complete balanced tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Properties_of_binary_trees) on line in O(n) time for a sorted input of length n. If you don't know the input size in advance, you can generate a tree where the left subtree of the root is perfect, and the right subtree is complete. If the input size is of the form 2^k-1, then the while tree will be perfect.The algorithm accumulates tree fragments in a stack and stitches them together as new elements arrive.

Comment: @Gene: the case where I don't know the size ahead of time sounds like what I'm interested in. Can you point me to a citation?

Comment: You might give this article a look:http://cglab.ca/~dana/pbst/

Answer (score -1):

To create a balanced tree, which I will guess you want to do, you will need to visit each node at least once. First, collect all the nodes into a buffer, and then recursively convert the buffer into a tree:

```
  def tfs[T](stream: Stream[T]): ImmutableTree[T] = {
    val ss = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[T]
    def treeFromSubsequence(start: Int, end: Int): ImmutableTree[T] =
      if (end == start) NilTree()
      else if (end - start == 1) ImmutableTreeNode(ss(start), NilTree(), NilTree())
      else {
        val mid = (end - start) / 2
        ImmutableTreeNode(ss(mid), treeFromSubsequence(start, mid), treeFromSubsequence(mid + 1, end))
      }
    stream.foreach { x => ss += x }
    treeFromSubsequence(0, ss.length)
  }
```

It will visit each value exactly twice, once to collect it and once to put it into the value field of a tree.

Comment: You don't need all the nodes up front. The simplest example is a [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), of which there are many types. There might be a version optimized for ordered insertion.

Comment: You're doing random access of all the elements in an array. The question notes that this answer was found elsewhere "After some cursory searching I was only able to find descriptions of techniques that involved storing a sorted array where you can access any element by index." The code provided in the question can already accomplish this with just streaming.

Comment: @JimMischel can you be more explicit? Which of those implementations uses persistent binary trees?

Comment: @StevenNoble None of those implementations is a persistent binary tree, but several could be modified for that purpose. I'm not an expert in persistent data structures, so I can't provide any particular details. The point of my comment here was that there's no requirement that the number of nodes, or the nodes themselves, be known up front.

Comment: If you can't or won't take advantage of knowledge that the stream is ordered or that the number of nodes can be known, then you will have an `O(N log N)` algorithm. The algorithm I present is `O(N)`